# base64 to numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raster

I have a pdf file which I converted into base64 and then decoded it into binary format i.e(010101010) like this. But I want this base64 encoded data to be in a NumPy array. So that it represents in raster binary form.

Below is the code I have tried so far. It is giving me into binary numbers but how to convert it into a NumPy 2D array.

```
with open("sample.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
    decoded = base64.decodebytes(encoded_string)
    decoded_binary_val= "".join(["{:08b}".format(x) for x in decoded])
    print(decoded_binary_val)
```

The result of the same is in (010101010111101011101010111101011111010101011) this format. But I want a NumPy 2D array i.e (r*c)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
arr = np.array([c for c in decoded_binary_val])
```

This will give you a numpy array of strings.
If you want numbers you can do:

```py
arr = np.array([int(c) for c in decoded_binary_val])
```

**Edit - Another option:**

If you want string values you can also just cast to list, like this:

```py
arr = np.array(list(decoded_binary_val))
```

But then if you want numbers you probably need to map:

```py
arr = np.array(list(map(int, decoded_binary_val)))
```

I haven't been able to measure a difference in performance, so you'll have to check with your setup.

Comment: I want it into a 2D NumPy array by height and width of the base64 image

Comment: Assuming you know the size, you can just use np.reshape on the 1d array.

Comment: Like arr.reshape((r, c)) for example.

Comment: That's the problem with how to get the size. I can't assume the size of pdf?

Comment: In that case that's a totally different issue. You can't get that from the byte stream unless it's stored in a header somewhere. Can't help you with that one.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, is that the byte stream you are reading is the raw file content with headers and layers and everything. A pdf file is not just an image, so you will need to parse all that information somehow.